# Unsecured Guest access on Macbook Pro

Tags: network

I am concerned that my personal, home based Macbook Pro guest network access may be being used by an outside source.  Is there a way for me to identify user access, time logged in / out, etc?

Comment: Please clarify "network access" To what? Aidrop, SSH, ftp, SCP. Which service

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$ cat /var/log/authd.log
```

This should show up events associated with user logins.

Comment: This is not always correct. When/if someone ssh's into a machine no entry is made to authd.log but rather /var/log/system.log (uname -smrp == Darwin 13.2.0 x86_64 i386) Original poster need to clarify: network access. To what? Aidrop, SSH, ftp, SCP... Which service